# Problem about Value passing reference passing in lambda

Tags: c++, lambda

Here is my code：

```
int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
    std::vector<int> v{4,3,2,1,3,3,3,3,4,3,2,1,3,3,3,3};
    std::mutex mtx;
    int i2=2;
    int i3=2;

    for_each(std::execution::par,v.begin(),v.end(),[i2,i3](const int& date)mutable{
        _sleep(1000);
        i2++;
        std::cout<<&i2<<std::endl;
        std::cout<<i2<<std::endl;
    });

    return 0;
}
```

and the result is：

```
0000001EF70FF540
0000001EF6FFF370
0000001EF6AFF240
0000001EF6EFF350
0000001EF71FF7E0
33

3
3
3
0000001EF72FFA70
3
0000001EF73FF7E0
3
0000001EF74FF6E0
3
0000001EF75FF8C0
3
0000001EF76FF9B0
3
0000001EF77FF5D0
3
0000001EF71FF7E0
3
0000001EF6AFF240
0000001EF70FF540
0000001EF6FFF370
0000001EF6EFF350
3
3
3
3
```

---

as you can see，for each loop,i2 got a new copy，and do the incremention on that copy.So we get 2++，the answer is 3.

But when I change a little part about that code：change

```
for_each(std::execution::par,v.begin(),v.end(),[i2,i3](const int& date)mutable{
```

to

```
for_each(std::execution::par,v.begin(),v.end(),[i2,&i3](const int& date)mutable{
```

since i2 always pass by value,the output should stay the same.But now the output is:

```
0000003ACCCFFB20
0000003ACCCFFB20
0000003ACCCFFB20
7
0000003ACCCFFB20
0000003ACCCFFB20
7
7
7
7
0000003ACCCFFB20
8
0000003ACCCFFB20
9
0000003ACCCFFB20
10
0000003ACCCFFB20
11
0000003ACCCFFB20
12
0000003ACCCFFB20
13
0000003ACCCFFB20
0000003ACCCFFB20
0000003ACCCFFB20
0000003ACCCFFB20
0000003ACCCFFB20
18
1818
18
18
```

---

I've check that address,it is indeed one copy of the original variable i2.But why only copy one time instead multi times？

Comment: On my machine it also works for the first example. I guess, it is not a problem of the labda, but with the parallel execution

Comment: @Armin Montigny     problem will still be there when not using parallel execution.

Comment: On my machine, the second example still works the same as the first

Comment: @smac89 you comment makes me surprise.And I run the code again under toolchain msvc.the result are different.Then I try it under mingw,find that the result are the same.So maybe it is the problem with msvc.